# Transport exception

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, thrift

I'm trying to import happybase but gets the following error message while connecting.
I have Hadoop pseudonode cluster and Hbase already running.
Version of the components installed are as follows,
Hadoop version - 1.0.4
Hbase version - 0.94.4
happybase -0.4

Can someone have a look into the exceptions below and let me know, if any thrift specific settings or any guidance in getting this fixed.

Thank you.

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import happybase

connection = happybase.Connection('localhost')

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/happybase/api.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.open()

    File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/happybase/api.py", line 138, in open
    self.transport.open()

    File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 149, in open
    return self.__trans.open()

    File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 99, in open
    message=message)

    thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:9090
```

Comment: Is the program on the other end listing on localhost:9090? You can check it out by accessing it via telnet.

Answer (score 8):

make sure you have thrift server started before you try to connect.

```
hbase thrift start -threadpool
```

Comment: Also, `hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift`.

Answer (score 0):

The trift server hast to be up and running. Your connection has to be opened as well:

```
nohup hbase thrift start &
```

Open connection in python before use:

```
connection.open()
```

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection('localhost', autoconnect=False)
connection.open()
```

Comment: `connection.open()` call is only required if `autoconnect=False`. The default value for `autoconnect` is `True`

Answer (score 0):

```
connection = happybase.Connection('localhost','2181')
```

Comment: Please add more of an explanation to your answer. As it stands, I'm not sure how much this addresses the question. (Also, as a suggestion, you can make a line appear without formatting (as if it were in a terminal) by prepending four spaces to the beginning of the line.

Comment: when you start thrift then you will be able to see what port it is using by reading it's standard output.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
sudo server hbase-thrift restart
```